# How to gracefully kill OSX application using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a script using subprocess that will launch an application at the terminal and later quit it. I'm trying to get the hang of subprocess, and my proficiency with terminal commands is somewhat shaky. (That's an understatement.)

Say the application is Mathematica. Then the following terminal commands will launch the application and quit it:

```
open -a Mathematica

osascript -e 'quit app "Mathematica"'
```

The suggestion for osascript I found at

https://osxdaily.com/2014/09/05/gracefully-quit-application-command-line/

In the python script, I can launch the application using

```
subprocess.Popen("open -a Mathematica", shell=True)
```

I've tried

```
subprocess.Popen("osascript -e 'quit app "Mathematica"'", shell=True)
```

and other variants but haven't been successful in closing the application.

I'm using Mac OS 10.15.4 with Python 3.7 in Idle.

Comment: Btw, have you tried to run `osascript -e 'quit app "Mathematica"'` in your terminal? Did it work?

Comment: Do you have escape characters in your string that defines the osascript command?  Did they just get lost in translation to the SO site?  I ask because what is displayed is invalid code due to embedded double quotes.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous - does that work for you?  My Mac doesn't have a "quit" command in its PATH.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous--to answer your question, the answer is "no", it did not work. 

I wanted to try your suggestion, which was just deleted. Was there an error in your proposed solution?

Comment: @Steve I meant `osascript -e 'quit app "Mathematica"'`. I don't have Mathematica installed on my machine, but I have tried the command with other apps and it does work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is invalid. This should do the trick:

```
subprocess.Popen("osascript -e 'quit app \"Mathematica\"'", shell=True)
```